# Sync Contact Adapter

Tags: java, android, android-contacts, android-syncadapter

[image]

I want to display my application name and icon on the user contact details like whatsapp icon.I will try to syncAdapter for this purpose.But i can not get in output.If anyone can you help me?

Authenticator Classs

```
public class Authenticator extends AbstractAccountAuthenticator {

    private final Context mContext;

    public Authenticator(Context context) {
        super(context);
        mContext = context;
    }

    @Override
    public Bundle editProperties(AccountAuthenticatorResponse response,
                                 String accountType) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public Bundle addAccount(AccountAuthenticatorResponse response,
                             String accountType, String authTokenType, String[] requiredFeatures,
                             Bundle options) throws NetworkErrorException {
        final Intent intent = new Intent(mContext, MainActivity.class);
        intent.putExtra(AccountManager.KEY_ACCOUNT_AUTHENTICATOR_RESPONSE, response);

        final Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
        bundle.putParcelable(AccountManager.KEY_INTENT, intent);
        return bundle;
    }

    @Override
    public Bundle confirmCredentials(AccountAuthenticatorResponse response,
                                     Account account, Bundle options) throws NetworkErrorException {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public Bundle getAuthToken(AccountAuthenticatorResponse response, Account account,
                               String authTokenType, Bundle options) throws NetworkErrorException {
        final Bundle result = new Bundle();
        result.putString(AccountManager.KEY_ACCOUNT_NAME, account.name);
        result.putString(AccountManager.KEY_ACCOUNT_TYPE, SyncStateContract.Constants.ACCOUNT_TYPE);
        return result;
    }

    @Override
    public String getAuthTokenLabel(String authTokenType) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public Bundle updateCredentials(AccountAuthenticatorResponse response, Account account,
                                    String authTokenType, Bundle options) throws NetworkErrorException {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public Bundle hasFeatures(AccountAuthenticatorResponse response, Account account,
                              String[] features) throws NetworkErrorException {
        return null;
    }
}
```

AuthenticatorService Class

```
public class AuthenticatorService extends Service {
    private Authenticator authenticator;

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        authenticator = new Authenticator(this);
    }

    /*
     * When the system binds to this Service to make the RPC call
     * return the authenticator’s IBinder.
     */
    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return authenticator.getIBinder();
    }
}
```

ContactManager Class

```
public class ContactsManager {

    private static String MIMETYPE = "vnd.android.cursor.item/com.example.syncadapter";

    public static void addContact(Context context,MyContact contact){
        ContentResolver resolver = context.getContentResolver();
        ArrayList<ContentProviderOperation> ops =
                new ArrayList<ContentProviderOperation>();

        ops.add(ContentProviderOperation
                .newInsert(addCallerIsSyncAdapterParameter(
                        ContactsContract.RawContacts.CONTENT_URI, true))
                .withValue(ContactsContract.RawContacts.ACCOUNT_NAME,
                        SyncStateContract.Constants.ACCOUNT_NAME)
                .withValue(ContactsContract.RawContacts.ACCOUNT_TYPE,
                        SyncStateContract.Constants.ACCOUNT_TYPE)
                .withValue(ContactsContract.RawContacts.AGGREGATION_MODE,
                        ContactsContract.RawContacts.AGGREGATION_MODE_DEFAULT)
                .build());

        ops.add(ContentProviderOperation
                .newInsert(addCallerIsSyncAdapterParameter(
                        ContactsContract.Data.CONTENT_URI, true))
                .withValueBackReference(ContactsContract.Data.RAW_CONTACT_ID, 0)
                .withValue(ContactsContract.Data.MIMETYPE,
                        ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.StructuredName.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE)
                .withValue(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.StructuredName.DISPLAY_NAME,
                        contact.name)
                .build());

        ops.add(ContentProviderOperation
                .newInsert(addCallerIsSyncAdapterParameter(
                        ContactsContract.Data.CONTENT_URI, true))
                .withValueBackReference(ContactsContract.Data.RAW_CONTACT_ID,0)
                .withValue(ContactsContract.Data.MIMETYPE, MIMETYPE)
                .withValue(ContactsContract.Data.DATA1, 12345)
                .withValue(ContactsContract.Data.DATA2, "user")
                .withValue(ContactsContract.Data.DATA3, "MyData")
                .build());

        try {
            resolver.applyBatch(ContactsContract.AUTHORITY, ops);
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    private static Uri addCallerIsSyncAdapterParameter(Uri uri,
                                                       boolean isSyncOperation) {
        if (isSyncOperation) {
            return uri.buildUpon()
                    .appendQueryParameter(ContactsContract.CALLER_IS_SYNCADAPTER,
                            "true").build();
        }
        return uri;
    }

}
```

MainActivity Class

```
ublic class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private ArrayList<String> mNames = new ArrayList<>();

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

//      Retrieve names from phone's contact list and save in mNames
        getNames();

//      Apply changes to phone's contact list
        new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                String name;
                for(int i=0;i<mNames.size();i++){
                    name = mNames.get(i);
                    ContactsManager.addContact(MainActivity.this, new MyContact(name));
                }
            }
        }).start();
    }

    private void getNames(){
        int hasPhone;
        Cursor c = getContentResolver().query(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI,
                null,null,null,null);
        if((c != null) && c.moveToFirst()){
            while(c.moveToNext()){
                hasPhone = Integer.parseInt(c.getString(
                        c.getColumnIndexOrThrow(ContactsContract.Contacts.HAS_PHONE_NUMBER)));
                if(hasPhone == 1)
                    mNames.add(c.getString(
                            c.getColumnIndexOrThrow(ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME)));
            }
            c.close();
        }
    }


}
```

MyContact Class for getting user name

```
public class MyContact {
    String name;
    public MyContact(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (this == o) return true;
        if (!(o instanceof MyContact)) return false;
        MyContact myContact = (MyContact) o;
        return Objects.equals(name, myContact.name);
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return Objects.hash(name);
    }
}
```

SyncAdapter class

```
public class SyncAdapter extends AbstractThreadedSyncAdapter {

    public SyncAdapter(Context context, boolean autoInitialize) {
        super(context, autoInitialize);
        Log.d("sync adapter","Sync Adapter created.");
    }

    @Override
    public void onPerformSync(Account account, Bundle extras,
                              String authority, ContentProviderClient provider,
                              SyncResult syncResult) {
        Log.d("sync adapter","Sync Adapter called.");
    }
}
```

SyncService class

```
public class SyncService extends Service {
    private static final Object sSyncAdapterLock = new Object();
    private static SyncAdapter mSyncAdapter = null;

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        Log.d("sync adapter","Sync Service created.");
        synchronized (sSyncAdapterLock){
            if(mSyncAdapter == null){
                mSyncAdapter = new SyncAdapter(getApplicationContext(),
                        true);
            }
        }
    }

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        Log.d("sync adapter","Sync Service binded.");
        return mSyncAdapter.getSyncAdapterBinder();
    }
}
```

Authenticator xml file

```
<account-authenticator
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:accountType="com.example.ajay.contacts_4"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:smallIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name" />
```

Contact xml file

```
<ContactsAccountType xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <ContactsDataKind
        android:mimeType="vnd.android.cursor.item/com.example.syncadapter.message"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:summaryColumn="data2"
        android:detailColumn="data3"/>
    <ContactsDataKind
        android:mimeType="vnd.android.cursor.item/com.example.syncadapter.voice"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:summaryColumn="data2"
        android:detailColumn="data3"/>
    <ContactsDataKind
        android:mimeType="vnd.android.cursor.item/com.example.syncadapter.video"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:summaryColumn="data2"
        android:detailColumn="data3"/>
</ContactsAccountType>
```

SyncAdapter xml file

```
<sync-adapter
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:contentAuthority="com.android.contacts"
android:accountType="com.example.syncadapter"
android:supportsUploading="false"
android:userVisible="true"/>
```

Manifest file

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    package="com.example.syncadapter">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.AUTHENTICATE_ACCOUNTS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MANAGE_ACCOUNTS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_SYNC_SETTINGS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_SYNC_SETTINGS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_CONTACTS" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:dataExtractionRules="@xml/data_extraction_rules"
        android:fullBackupContent="@xml/backup_rules"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.SyncAdapter"
        tools:targetApi="31">
        <activity
            android:name=".AuthenticatorActivity"
            android:exported="false" />
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:exported="true">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
                <data android:mimeType="vnd.android.cursor.item/com.example.syncadapter.message" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <service android:name=".AuthenticatorService"
            tools:ignore="Instantiatable"
            android:exported="true">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.accounts.AccountAuthenticator" />
            </intent-filter>

            <meta-data
                android:name="android.accounts.AccountAuthenticator"
                android:resource="@xml/authenticator" />
        </service>

        <service android:name=".SyncService"
            android:exported="true">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.content.SyncAdapter" />
            </intent-filter>

            <meta-data
                android:name="android.content.SyncAdapter"
                android:resource="@xml/syncadapter" />
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.provider.CONTACTS_STRUCTURE"
                android:resource="@xml/contacts" />
        </service>

    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: That is a whole lot of code! Can you boil it down to a minimal example reproducing the problem? Only few people will take the time to read through all of it

Comment: @NekoSenpai Hi, can you add the code for the two xml files, "data_extraction_rules" and "backup_rules"?

Comment: No.Could you tell me xml file contents?